# how to use libconfig to read several config files in one object?

Tags: c++, libconfig

Assume I have a `libconfig::config` object, can i `readFile` for several times like this:

```
libconfig::Config cfg;
cfg.readFiles("./a.cfg");
cfg.readFiles("./b.cfg");
```

and what will happen if `a.cfg` and `b.cfg` have same key?

If this doesnt work, is there any methods can let me merge two config files' setting into one object?

Answer (score 0):

At first, it seems that method is `readFile()` not `readFiles()` unless I'm checking incorrect library.

Second, everytime `readFile()` is called, values in config will be reset. So after `cfg.readFiles("./b.cfg");` you will not have `a.cfg` configuration anymore.

Comment: ok....  any ideas to merge config settings from several config files?

Comment: @nick I don't know. I just quickly checked lib and checked how readfile works